# Qml - passing property value between two components

Tags: qt, properties, qml, components

This is a simplification of the situation I am dealing with in main.qml file:

```
Component {
 id: component1
 property string stringIneedToPass: "Hello"
 Text { text: stringIneedToPass }
}
Component {
 id: component2
 Rectangle {
  id: myRectangle
  property string stringIneedToReceive = component1.stringIneedToPass; //this doesn't work
 }
}
```

Obviously my situation is more complicated. But in the end I just need to understand how this kind of transfer should be done!

Thank you all!

Comment: As @dtech pointed out, there are various issues with your code. You can only assign or bind the properties of a Component's Object upon instantiation. To provide a possible better way of doing it, you should provide details on how you are planing on instantiating your Components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `Component` element cannot have properties. `Component`s are either loaded from files, or defined declaratively, in the latter case they can contain only one single root element and an id.

Second - you cannot do assignment in the body of an element, only bindings.

Third - you cannot reference properties defined inside an element inside a component from the outside, as that object doesn't exist until the component is instantiated. Such objects can only be referenced from inside.

Other than that, it will work as expected, if you can reference it, you can bind or assign it to a property, depending on what you want.

So you can simply have the string property external:

```
  property string stringIneedToPass: "Hello"

  Component {
    id: component1
    Text {
      text: stringIneedToPass
    }
  }

  Component {
    id: component2
    Rectangle {
      id: myRectangle
      property string stringIneedToReceive: stringIneedToPass
    }
  }
```